# What's the difference between mkfs and mkdosfs?

Tags: gnome, command-line, usb, bash

I'm trying to put a linux distro .iso on my usb and the instructions suggests using the following command to make a fat32 filesystem:

```
mkdosfs -F 32 /dev/sdc1
```

Is there a reason this command is to be used instead of mkfs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

mkfs is a command to make a file system, and is a front end for the more specific mkfs.file_type (mkfs.vfat , mkfs.ext4, etc)

> In actuality, mkfs is simply a front-end for the  various  file  system
>          builders (mkfs.fstype) available under Linux.  The file system-specific
>          builder is searched for in a number of directories like perhaps  /sbin,
>          /sbin/fs,  /sbin/fs.d,  /etc/fs,  /etc  (the precise list is defined at
>          compile time but at least contains /sbin and /sbin/fs), and finally  in
>          the  directories  listed  in the PATH environment variable.  Please see
>          the file system-specific builder manual pages for further details.

mkfs.vfat is a symbolilc link to mkdosfs

They are the same

```
ls -l /sbin/mkfs.vfat
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 2011-10-29 23:13 /sbin/mkfs.vfat -> mkdosfs
```

For additional information see

[man mkfs](http://lrwxrwxrwx%201%20root%20root%207%202011-10-29%2023:13%20/sbin/mkfs.vfat%20-%3E%20mkdosfs)

Comment: You are most welcome.